# Boost r-tree "correct" way to access objects

Tags: c++, boost, r-tree

**TLDR**: is there a way to update object directly in a Boost r-tree (by setting the location class property to const, or something similar)?

**More info:**

I am using C++ Boost's R-tree to store objects with spatial coordinates (for reference, please see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64179718/storing-or-accessing-objects-in-boost-r-tree)). For the sake of the discussion, let's assume my objects are `City`-ies with spatial cartesian coordinates and some class properties; say population and size.

Currently, I have a separate `std::map` whose keys are some indices and values are the `City` objects. In the tree, as suggested in the answer to my previous question, I store some struct whose fields are the `City` index and its coordinates. When I need update a `City` class property, all I do is search for the city in the tree, and update the `std::map`:

```
// The struct stored in the tree
struct CityRef {
        size_t index;
        point location;
};

typedef bgi::rtree< CityRef, bgi::quadratic<16>, bgi::indexable<CityRef>,  index::equal_to<CityRef> > rtree_t;

//A map storing the cities:
std::map<size_t, City *> cityDict;
```

I think that just for code readably, it would be much more comprehensible if I did not need to store a separate `City` map. Is there a way to directly update the object stored in the tree? I understand this may lead to unwanted behavior, as the tree needs to be re-balanced if the `location` property is ever changed. However, at least conceptually, it would be nice if there was a way to define just the `location` field as a `const` (so it couldn't be changed), and do something like:

```
City::City() {
const point location;
double population;
double size;
}
```

And store that object in the tree:

```
typedef bgi::rtree< City, bgi::quadratic<16>, index::indexable<City>,  index::equal_to<City> > rtree_t;
```

Then, it would be possible to use a nearest neighbor iterator `rtree_t::const_query_iterator it` scroll through the values, and do something like

```
it->population = newPopulation;
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it. One of the devs entertained a few ideas to work in non-const data in this old [mailing list](http://boost-geometry.203548.n3.nabble.com/Are-all-query-iterators-const-td4026626.html) e-mail. But that was in 2015 and today there is no non-const query iterator in the public namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to store mutable values in the rtree right now.

You could store the point and index in the rtree and then the rest of the data in a different container. It could be vector/deque if the index is preserved (you don't remove elements from the container) or map if you need sorting by key or unoredered_map if you don't. So e.g.:

```
struct data_t { double population; double size; };
point_t point;

bgi::rtree<std::pair<point_t, size_t>, bgi::quadratic<16>> rt;
std::unordered_map<size_t, data_t> umap;
for (auto it = rt.qbegin(bgi::nearest(point, 3)); it != rt.qend(); ++it)
    data_t& data = umap[it->second];
```

Another option would be to use `const_cast` and be careful to not modify the location. So something like:

```
point_t point;
bgi::rtree<City, bgi::quadratic<16>> rt;
for (auto it = rt.qbegin(bgi::nearest(point, 3)); it != rt.qend(); ++it)
    const_cast<double&>(it->population) = 123.4;
```